# Links missing from Bootstrap navbar for desktop screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to follow the bootstrap 3 examples, but I have a problem with the navbar that I seem unable to resolve.  With the following html, the navbar items are present as expected in the toggle menu when the viewport is thin (mobile style), but when expanded to a reasonable desktop width, the navbar links ("example left 1", "example left 2", and "example right 1" in the html below) all disappear completely.  What have I left out that makes them disappear?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Server</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Server</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collpase collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Example left 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example left 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Example right 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container body-content">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you misspelled collapse in here: `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collpase collapse">`

Comment: I... don't want to talk about how long I was looking for that mistake.